# Remove last field with spaces and (optional) single quotes as field separators

Tags: awk

I've got a file with following example strings:

```
set system login user alice full-name 'Alice Example'
set system login user alice level admin
```

and need to remove the last field.

For this I use awk this way but that does not work for strings with spaces enclosed in single quotes:

```
$ echo "set system login user alice full-name 'Alice Example'" | awk '{$NF=""; print}'
set system login user alice full-name 'Alice
```

so I add the space and single quote as field separators, but that also does not give the expected output:

```
$ echo "set system login user alice full-name 'Alice Example'" | awk -F "[ ']" '{$NF=""; print}'
set system login user alice full-name  Alice Example
```

what am I doing wrong and how should I do it to get only `set system login user alice full-name` ?

EDIT: Thank you for your answers! Because it was asked for, here a complete example of the file I am working on:

```
set firewall all-ping enable
set firewall broadcast-ping disable
set firewall group port-group WebServices0xFF port 8080
set firewall group port-group WebServices0xFF port 8081
set firewall group port-group WebServices0xFF port 9090
set firewall group port-group WebServices0xFF port 9091
set firewall group port-group WebServices0xFF port 2006
set firewall group port-group WebServices0xFF port 2007
set firewall group port-group WebServices0xFF port 8000
set firewall group port-group WebServices0xFF port 10443
set firewall ipv6-receive-redirects disable
set firewall ipv6-src-route disable
set firewall ip-src-route disable
set firewall log-martians enable
set firewall receive-redirects disable
set firewall send-redirects enable
set firewall source-validation disable
set firewall syn-cookies enable
set interfaces bridge br1 address 10.12.34.100/24
set interfaces bridge br1 aging 300
set interfaces bridge br1 bridged-conntrack disable
set interfaces bridge br1 hello-time 2
set interfaces bridge br1 max-age 20
set interfaces bridge br1 priority 32768
set interfaces bridge br1 promiscuous disable
set interfaces bridge br1 stp false
set interfaces ethernet eth0 duplex auto
set interfaces ethernet eth0 poe output off
set interfaces ethernet eth0 speed auto
set interfaces ethernet eth0 vif 1100 bridge-group bridge br1
set interfaces ethernet eth1 duplex auto
set interfaces ethernet eth1 poe output 24v
set interfaces ethernet eth1 speed auto
set interfaces ethernet eth1 vif 1100 bridge-group bridge br1
set interfaces ethernet eth2 duplex auto
set interfaces ethernet eth2 poe output 24v
set interfaces ethernet eth2 speed auto
set interfaces ethernet eth2 vif 1100 bridge-group bridge br1
set interfaces ethernet eth3 duplex auto
set interfaces ethernet eth3 poe output 24v
set interfaces ethernet eth3 speed auto
set interfaces ethernet eth3 vif 1100 bridge-group bridge br1
set interfaces ethernet eth4 duplex auto
set interfaces ethernet eth4 poe output 24v
set interfaces ethernet eth4 speed auto
set interfaces ethernet eth4 vif 1100 bridge-group bridge br1
set interfaces ethernet eth5 duplex auto
set interfaces ethernet eth5 speed auto
set interfaces ethernet eth5 vif 1100 bridge-group bridge br1
set interfaces loopback lo
set interfaces switch switch0 mtu 1500
set interfaces wireguard wg0 mtu 1420
set interfaces wireguard wg0 peer 1syRMYD1jIVFMUMm5hF/j0MzjMQmuC5mlcT1VVugIkU= allowed-ips 172.27.0.0/24
set interfaces wireguard wg0 peer 1syRMYD1jIVFMUMm5hF/j0MzjMQmuC5mlcT1VVugIkU= allowed-ips 10.5.44.0/24
set interfaces wireguard wg0 peer 1syRMYD1jIVFMUMm5hF/j0MzjMQmuC5mlcT1VVugIkU= endpoint 'wireguard.example.org:51820'
set interfaces wireguard wg0 peer 1syRMYD1jIVFMUMm5hF/j0MzjMQmuC5mlcT1VVugIkU= persistent-keepalive 25
set interfaces wireguard wg0 peer 1syRMYD1jIVFMUMm5hF/j0MzjMQmuC5mlcT1VVugIkU= preshared-key wQ*obfuscated*X9/mf*obfuscated*yYM1/qcQeRow=
set interfaces wireguard wg0 private-key WG4ZY8OD*obfuscated*7mW*obfuscated*0+5qoZ28=
set interfaces wireguard wg0 route-allowed-ips true
set service gui http-port 81
set service gui https-port 10443
set service gui older-ciphers enable
set service lldp interface all
set service pppoe-server authentication local-users username test1gw1 password kh93BsG4
set service pppoe-server authentication local-users username test1gw1 static-ip 1.2.3.5
set service pppoe-server authentication mode local
set service pppoe-server client-ip-pool start 0.0.0.0
set service pppoe-server client-ip-pool stop 0.0.0.100
set service pppoe-server dns-servers server-1 9.9.9.9
set service pppoe-server dns-servers server-2 1.1.1.1
set service pppoe-server interface eth0
set service pppoe-server local-ip 1.2.3.4
set service snmp community o-obfuscated-f authorization ro
set service snmp contact someone@example.org
set service snmp location '1234, Teststreet 1'
set service ssh port 10
set service ssh protocol-version v2
set service unms disable
set system analytics-handler send-analytics-report false
set system crash-handler send-crash-report false
set system domain-name sub.example.org
set system host-name test-router
set system login banner post-login ''
set system login banner pre-login ''
set system login user alice authentication encrypted-password '$5$4*obfuscated*A$2*obfuscated*Q/.S*obfuscated*0/v*obfuscated*A'
set system login user alice authentication plaintext-password ''
set system login user alice authentication public-keys openpgp key AAAAB3N*obfuscated*
set system login user alice full-name 'Alice Example'
set system login user alice level admin
set system name-server 9.9.9.9
set system name-server '2001:4860:4860::8888'
set system name-server '2001:4860:4860::8844'
set system ntp server 0.ubnt.pool.ntp.org
set system ntp server 1.ubnt.pool.ntp.org
set system ntp server 2.ubnt.pool.ntp.org
set system ntp server 3.ubnt.pool.ntp.org
set system options reboot-on-panic true
set system syslog global facility all level notice
set system syslog global facility protocols level debug
set system syslog host 10.5.44.205 facility all level err
set system time-zone Europe/Vienna
```

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Sorry, I thought the last line of my question would be enough as "desired output". I updated/edited the question to add the full (obfuscated) file that needs to be edited.

Comment: No-one asked for "a complete example of the file I am working on", what was   asked for is the expected output given your posted sample input. Posting 100 lines of text you just happen to have lying around isn't useful for sample input, and posting input without the expected output is only half of the example.

Answer (score 3):

Using any POSIX awk:

```
$ awk '{sub(/[[:space:]]+(\047[^\047]*\047|[^[:space:]]+)$/,"")} 1' file
set system login user alice full-name
set system login user alice level
```

You can reduce that to:

```
$ awk "{sub(/ ('[^']*'|[^ ])$/,x)} 1" file
set system login user alice full-name
set system login user alice level
```

for your specific single-blank-separated input if you aren't going to do anything else in this awk script and so using double quotes as delimiter won't make that harder.

Answer (score 2):

You may use gnu-awk with `FPAT` like this:

```bash
awk -v FPAT="'[^']*'|[^[:blank:]]+" '{
   $NF = ""; sub(/[[:blank:]]+$/, "")} 1' file

set system login user alice full-name
set system login user alice level
```

Here:

- `FPAT="'[^']*'|[^[:blank:]]+"`: Sets field pattern to a single quoted string or 1+ non-whitespace substring.
- `$NF = ""`: Blanks out last file
- `sub(/[[:blank:]]+$/, "")`: Removes trailing spaces on each line

---

For non-gnu `awk`, we can consider this solution using `match` and `substr` functions:

```bash
awk "{print substr(\$0, 1, match(\$0, / +('[^']*'|[^ ]+)$/)-1)}" file
```

Comment: That would replace each set of contiguous white space on the line with a single blank char which may or may not be desirable.

Comment: Yes that's right, it's been tested with the given examples

Answer (score 1):

```
# grep -oP ".*(?= \w+$|\'.*\'$)" file
set system login user alice full-name 
set system login user alice level
```